# Scala; How can I iterate through a list and iterate through another list within each iteration

Tags: scala

I will try to explain my question as well as I can.

So I have a list of stock items, within a delivery. I would like to be able to iterate through this list and find the matching product id by iterating through a product list until the product id of the stock items list and the product list match and then increment product quantities.

So the StockItem class looks like this:

```
case class StockItem(val spiId : Int, val pId :Int, val sdId :Int, val quan : Int)
```

And my Product class looks like this:

```
case class Product(val prodId : Int, val name : String, val desc : String, val price : Double, var quantity : Int, val location : String)
```

I have a method to find all the StockItems that have a particular spId, which returns a list of StockItems:

```
def findAllItemsInSP(sdId: Int): List[StockPurchaseItem] = stockPurchaseItems2.filter(_.sdId == sdId)
```

I have another method which is unfinished to iterate through this list and increment the quantities of each product:

```
    def incrementStock(spID: Int){
      val items = StockPurchaseItem.findAllItemsInSP(spID)

    for (i <- items){
      if(i.pId == products.prodId)
    }
  }
```

products is a set of Product objects. Obviously products.prodId doesn't work as I need to be refering to one element of the products Set, not the whole set. I don't know how to find the matching product id in the set of Products. Any help given, I would be very grateful for.

Note: sdId and spId refer to the same thing.

Many thanks
Jackie

Answer (score 2):

1st - All parameters to a `case class` are automatically class values, so you don't need those `val` labels.

2nd - You say you "have a method to find all the StockItems that have a particular spId", but the code is filtering for `_.sdId == sdId`. spId? sdId? A bit confusing.

3rd - You say that "`products` is a set of Project objects."  Did you mean `Product` objects?  I don't see any "Project" code.

So, one thing you could do is make `items` a `Map[Int,Int]`, which translates `pId` to quantity, but with a default of zero.

```
val items = StockPurchaseItem.findAllItemsInSP(spID).map(x => (x.spId, x.quantity)).toMap.withDefaultValue(0)
```

Now you can walk through `products`, incrementing every quantity by `items(spId)`.

```
products.foreach(p => p.quantity += items(p.spId)) // or something like that
```

Comment: Thank you sorry there were some typos, I will correct them now

Answer (score 2):

You could do it with a 'for-comprehension' [Docs](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/sequence-comprehensions.html) in a similar method to below.

```
val stockItems: List[StockItem] = ???
val products: List[Product] = ???
val result: List[Product] = for{
    item <- stockItems
    p <- products
    if p.prodId == item.pId
} yield { p.copy(quan = p.quan + 1) } //I expect you'd want different logic to this
```

Comment: This is probably the most straightforward and efficient way to do this.

Comment: Check scala style guide regarding comprehensions: http://docs.scala-lang.org/style/control-structures.html#comprehensions Try avoiding semicolons.

Comment: Sorry I was just being lazy since I didn't have a code editor available and wanted to be safe. 
Made edit, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
def incrementStock(spID: Int){
  val items = StockPurchaseItem.findAllItemsInSP(spID)

for (i <- items) {
  for (p <- products) {
    if(i.pId == p.prodId)
      products += p
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I dont wish to update the quantity by 1, I wish to obtain the new quantity by summing together the existing quantity with the quantity received for that product in the new stock delivery.

Comment: So you want to add it to the products? I edited my response.

Answer (score -1):

Ok I have managed to do what I wanted to do by creating a new Product with the existing properties with that product id and then adding to the quantity.

```
def incrementStock(spID: Int){
      val items = StockPurchaseItem.findAllItemsInSP(spID)

    for (i <- items){
      var currentProd: Product = Product(Product.findProduct(i.pId).get.prodId, Product.findProduct(i.pId).get.name, Product.findProduct(i.pId).get.desc, Product.findProduct(i.pId).get.price, Product.findProduct(i.pId).get.quantity, Product.findProduct(i.pId).get.location)
      currentProd.quantity += i.quan

      products -= (findProduct(i.pId).get)
      products = products + currentProd
    }

    printProductInfo()
  }
```